# .htaccess Not Redirecting To requested page

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, redirect

I built an application with laravel and redirected all request from my old-domain.com to my new-domain.com using this line of .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?old-domain\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.new-domain.org/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But when I visit `https://www.new-domain.org/requestedPage` I get redirected to `https://www.new-domain.org/index.php` instead of to `https://www.new-domain.org/requestedPage`.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi guys, I figured it out. I uninstall my SSL on the old-domain and it worked perfectly.
Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's been already answered by the OP

Comment: @recoverymen I would love to see your solution.
Thanks

Comment: make your htaccess as 

 `Options +FollowSymLinks



RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://maskingdomain.com/ [R=302,NC]`

Comment: i test it as if i put this htacess i an new folder as i enter in the folder it redirects me to http://maskingdomain.com/